# Angular retrieve all facebook taggable friends

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve all Facebook taggable friends of a user. Since Facebook only returns 25 friends at one time. I want to add a button to load next list of users

( I know I can increase the limit. but 25 per request is sufficient since it'll reduce user's bandwidth and speed up the website).

facebook API return  **"after" (cursor), "before" (cursor ) and "next" (access token)**  but I cannot understand how to use those in a button to retrieve next list of friends

I'm using ngx - facebook plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-facebook-sdk

I use this function to retrieve data

```
 public friends() {

    this.fb.api('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name,picture.type(large)')
      .then((res: any) => {
       console.log('Got the users profile', res);
        this.fbfriends = res.data;

      })
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

> facebook return array of **25 user data  ,  after cursor , before
>   cursor & next =**
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/10203919785370453/taggable_friends?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

code for user data array  display on the webpage

```
  <div class="card-group">
  <div class="col-5"  *ngFor="let user of fbfriends">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ user.picture.data.url}}">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ user.name }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved  issue by myself. all you need to do is  get facebook api path to a string & replace this part

> /me/taggable_friends?fields=name,picture.type(large)

```
fbnext = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/10203919785370453/taggable_friends?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 

     public friends() {

        this.fb.api(fbnext)
          .then((res: any) => {
           console.log('Got the users profile', res);
            this.fbfriends = res.data;

          })
          .catch(this.handleError);

      }
```